# Node CryptoJS vs Jsrsasign SHA256withRSA with encrypted pem

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rsa, cryptojs

So I am running into an issue using jsrsasign. I am not quite what I am doing wrong.
I am attempting to emulate a hash process we are uinsg in NodeJS using angular and it is not clear what the issue is.
Here is the process in we have in NodeJS that works perfect

```
var restler = require('restler');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');

var sha_hash = crypto.createHash('SHA1');
var pem = fs.readFileSync('private-key.pem');
var pkey = pem.toString('ascii');

var private_key = {
    key: pkey,
    passphrase:'password'
}

//var current_date = new Date();
//console.log(dateFormat(current_date, "yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:ss l"));
var current_date = '2015/05/06 20:07:12 926';

//SToken
sha_hash.update(current_date);
var stoken = sha_hash.digest('hex');
console.log(stoken);

//Signature
var signature = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256')
signature.update(stoken);
var sig = signature.sign(private_key, 'base64');
console.log(sig);
```

Both the SToken Values and the Signature Values produce the expected results
if we try something similar using angularjs, the Signature value is incorrect.

Here is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body ng-app="main">
<div ng-view>
</div>
</body>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/dateformat/dist/dateformat.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/yahoo/yahoo-min.js">    </script>

<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/core.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/x64-core.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/pbkdf2.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/hmac.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/sha1.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/sha256.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/ext/base64.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/ext/jsbn.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/ext/jsbn2.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/ext/rsa.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/ext/rsa2.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/crypto-1.1.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/rsasign-1.2.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/rsapem-1.1.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/asn1-1.0.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/asn1hex-1.1.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/keyutil-1.0.js"></script>

<script src="modules/authentication/authentication.module.js"></script>
<script src="modules/authentication/authentication.controller.js"></script>
<script src="app.js" ></script>
</html>
```

And here is the authentication.controller.js file:

```
(function (authenticationModule) {

    var authenticationController = function($scope, $http, $q, $filter) {

        var deferred = $q.defer()
        var private_key = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'private-key.pem'
        }).success(function(privateKey) {
            deferred.resolve();

            //var current_date = new Date();
            //var date_string = $filter('date')(current_date, "yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:ss SSS");
            var date_string = '2015/05/06 20:07:12 926';

            //SToken
            var stoken = CryptoJS.SHA1(date_string).toString();
            console.log(stoken);
            $scope.stoken = stoken;

            //Signature
            var sig = new KJUR.crypto.Signature({"alg": "SHA256withRSA", "prov": "cryptojs/jsrsa"});

            sig.init(privateKey, 'password');
            sig.updateString(stoken);
            var signature = sig.sign();
            console.log(signature);
            $scope.signature = signature;
        }).error(function(error) {
            console.error("there was an error reading file");
            deferred.reject(error);
        });

    };

    authenticationModule.controller('authenticationController', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', '$filter', authenticationController]);


}(angular.module('authentication')));
```

And here is the authentication.module.js file

```
(function (angular) {

    'use strict';
    //Initialize the Module
    angular.module('authentication',[]);

}(window.angular));
```

Here is the app.js file:

```
(function(angular){

    //Defines my angular main portion of the application
    var module = angular.module('main',['ngRoute', 'authentication']);


    //Defines the routes
    module
        .config(function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider
                .when('/auth',{     templateUrl:'modules/authentication/authentication.view.html',  controller:'authenticationController'})
                .otherwise({redirectTo:'/auth'});
        });

})(window.angular);
```

And finally here is the view:

```
<div>
    SToken: {{stoken}}
</div>
<div>
    Signature: {{signature}}
</div>
```

Again, just to repeat, the SToken value appears correct but when I show the signature, it is incorrect. I am not quite sure how to deal with this but any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I realize that I forgot to base64 encode the answer from angularjs

So I changed the controller.js code from this

```
var signature = sig.sign();
```

To this:

```
var signature = hextob64(sig.sign());
```

I also has to update the index.html file to include this library

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/base64x-1.1.js"></script>
```

Everything matched once I added these changes.